# Trouble finding page. Django url / views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

this is the first time I had to ask something at StackOverflow, I'm both excited and scared, I don't know why.
I'm writing a Django app that just hosts web posts. The page is divided into three (3) categories (Index, lkmi and chiqung). Each post has a category (lkmi or chiqung).
On the INDEX page, you can see all the posts.
On the LKMI page, you can see only the lkmi posts.
On the CHIQUNG page, you can see only the chiqung posts.
All is controlled just by ONE VIEW called "index_page", which receives an argument called "cat" that is the URL from one of the categories (index, lkmi, chiqung). Based on that it dictates which posts to load.

*** NOW THE PROBLEM ***

I can't find why, but I'm only having trouble loading the lkmi section. The index page and the chiqung_page loads perfectly, but I'm having a

```
"Page Not Found (404)
 Request Method: GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/lkmi/
```

Using the URLconf defined in blog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
 admin/
 <cat> [name='index_page']
 post/<int:pk> [name='post_detallado']
 ^ckeditor/
```

The current path, lkmi/, didn't match any of these.
"
I'll leave here the models, views and urls.
**Models**
Category

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    presentation = RichTextUploadingField(default='')
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='',null=False,blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Categoria")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Categorias")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_postes(self):
        print('Entre get_postes')
        if self.url == '/':
            return Post.objects.all().order_by('-published_date')
        else:
            return Post.objects.filter(category=self.pk).order_by('-published_date')
```

Post

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(('Titulo'),max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey("core.Category", verbose_name=("Categoria"), null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    author = models.CharField(("Autor/a"), max_length=50, default='El Autor')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Post")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Postes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

**View That Handles The Categorization**

```
def index_page(request, cat):
    print('function index_page')
    print('cat ='+str(cat))
    category = get_object_or_404(Category,url=cat)
    print('get_object_or_404(Category,url=cat). Executed')
    print(str(category))
    postes = category.get_postes()
    print('category.get_postes(). Executed')
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'postes': postes,
                                         'category': category})
```

**URL file from the app**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
    path('<cat>', views.index_page, name='index_page'),
    path('post/<int:pk>', views.detailed_post, name='detailed_post'),
]
```

**Index Page**
[It loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMGyg.png)
**Chiqung Page**
[It loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gKvP.png)
**LKMI Page**
[It doesn't load...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlLir.png)

If i use python manage.py shell and look for the category using `Category.objects.get(url='lkmi')` it returns the desired Category. Based on the **comments of the view**, it **doesn't even enter the view function**, because in the console it doesn't output "function index_page", even though it is the first line of the function.

Also, if i try the url "**127.0.0.1:8000/lkmi" it gives

```
Using the URLconf defined in blog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. admin/ - 
2. <cat> name='index_page'] - 
3. post/<int:pk> [name='post_detallado'].
```

But if i just enter "**127.0.0.1:8000/whatever**" the error is just

```
No Categoria matches the given query.
```

So in this case it entered the function and it gave the 404 error of not finding a matching Category. I still can't understand why it doens't execute the view when i try to enter to the **lkmi** url..

Thank you very much, I hope someone can help me with this so I cant continue going.

Comment: Your class is called "Category", but you call `get_object_or_404()` on "Categoria"

Comment: Oh im sorry, thats just becouse i programmed it in spanish, i changed it to english to ask the question, thats just in the stack overflow question, but thanks for noticing.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have a Category object with exactly "lkmi" in the url field?

Comment: 100% sure...If i use **python manage.py shell** and look for the category using ""Category.objects.get(url='lkmi')"" it returns the desired Category. Based on the comments of the view, it doesn't even enter the view function, because in the console it doesn't output "function index_page", even though it is the first line of the function.

Comment: Also, if i try the url "127.0.0.1:8000/lkmi" it gives                                                  
**Using the URLconf defined in blog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 1. admin/ - 2.<cat> name='index_page'] - 3. post/<int:pk> [name='post_detallado'].** But if i just enter "127.0.0.1:8000/whatever" the error is just **No Categoria matches the given query.**, so in this case it entered the function and it gave the 404 error of not finding a matching Category. I still can't understand why it doens't execute the view when i try to enter to the lkmi url..

Comment: Does it make a difference if you include a "/" at the end of the url? i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/lkmi` vs `http://127.0.0.1:8000/lkmi/` ?

Comment: By default, when i click the **lkmi** link url has the "**/**" at the end. The other categories **don't**, even thow they go trough the same template and view. The value of the url field is just "lkmi".  If I put the "**/**" at the end of any of the url  categories (ex: **127.0.0.1:8000/index/**) it gives the same error as with **lkmi**, so that may lead us to the answer.                                                                                   P.S: I'm not able to enter "**127.0.0.1:8000/lkmi**" because it changes to "**127.0.0.1:8000/lkmi/**" automatically.

Comment: try in urls to add a backslash after <cat> changing to: `path('<cat>/', views.index_page, name='index_page'),`

Comment: I was just trying that, that solves the loading of the **lkmi** category. But when you try to enter other category, it concatenates the url... >"**27.0.0.1:8000/lkmi**" > click index link > "**127.0.0.1:8000/lkmi/index**"... Instead of going to "**27.0.0.1:8000/index**"

Comment: the concatenating happens because of how your `a href` is written. `<a href="/index">index</a>` should take you where you want to go,  `<a href="index">index</a>` will concatenate the url.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. Now i can enter any category. But I still don't understand why it throwed **only** the **lkmi** url with the "**/**" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is called "Category", but you call `get_object_or_404()` on "Categoria"

View should be:

```
def index_page(request, cat):
    categoria = get_object_or_404(Category,url=cat)
    postes = categoria.get_postes()
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'postes': postes,
                                         'categoria': categoria})
```

Comment: Oh im sorry, thats becouse i programmed it in spanish, i changed it to english to ask the question, thats just in the stack overflow question not in my code, but thanks for noticing...   If that would be the error it would fail to load whenever i try to load any of the pages, not just the lkmi page, since every category is loaded trough the same view (index_page)